# Using sigaction for SIGCHLD to know when children terminate but unable to tell when the child SIGSEVs

Tags: c, linux, signals

According to the man page for sigaction, if we use it with SIGCHLD then in our handler function - this is if we use `void (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);`

the `si_code` member of the `siginfo_t` structure should contain the reason the signal was sent.

I am interested in these reasons...

```
CLD_EXITED
CLD_KILLED
CLD_DUMPED
```

Now my question is... even if the child exited abnormally (i.e by executing buggy code to
cause a crash) i still get `CLD_EXITED`. I assumed I should get `CLD_DUMPED` instead.
As for `CLD_KILLED`, if I kill a child process, I get this one correctly.

What am I missing? In my parent process, I need to know if any of the child processes terminate abruptly.

I am causing the abrupt error by trying to write to a null pointer but I need to know of any kind of abnormal termination. It is not necessary to know exactly what or how it happened.

When is the `CLD_DUMPED` generated?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the `si_code` given to the signal handler, you should simply be looking at the exit status from `waitpid` (or one of the other `wait`-family functions) to determine the cause of exit. The macros `W*` from `sys/wait.h`, when applied to the status `int`, will tell you the cause of termination.

Comment: The reason I was trying si_code is that I am not getting the correct value from the W* macros too. WIFSIGNALED is always returning false even when the child has clearly been signaled for trying to write to invalid memory.

Comment: Then either your use of `WIFSIGNALED` is wrong (maybe you're passing the return value of `wait` rather than the `int status` whose address you passed to `wait`?) or the child is trapping `SIGSEGV` and then exiting normally...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `CLD_DUMPED` is caused when the process dumps core.